# How Kafka Revoke Topic Partitions mechanism Works in 0.9.0.1?

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I am bit confused with **Kafka Revoke partition mechanism** (may be i have implemented my java code bit different.)

As far as i understand:

1. Under **1st Topic** if there are 'N' no. of partitions, 'N' No. of
   consumers can consume messages on that topic and when ever new
   consumer subscribes to that topic Revoke will occur and partitions
   will be re-assigned between those 'N' Consumers.
2. Now if consumer subscribes to **2nd Topic** with multiple Partitions, my
   understanding is that Revoke partition on 1st Topic should not
   happen (OR it will?)

Comment: For the first point, why there still has N consumers if new consumer subscribes to the topic?

Comment: N is just a number here if you still add more N+1,2,3 again it will be N. so N is infinite no.s, But Consumers are always equal to No of topic partitions.

Answer (score 0):

Revoke usually happens when there is a repartitioning happening. Consider the scenario you have 5 partitions for a topic which 3 consumers under a consumer group are listening to.

Since no of partitions > no of consumers, the consumers jump between partitions at regular intervals. This process is called rebalancing.

Consider consumer 1 is connected to say partition 1 and fetches a batch of messages, process, and then send an acknowledgment back to the broker for these message offsets. But if the consumer is taking more time to send acknowledge for the message batch and a rebalance has happened (i.e consumer 1 left partition 1 and went for some other partition) then this partition revoked event will be thrown.